# Omitting "tio" in "tio, kion"

Tags: correlatives

I remember that "tio" can be omitted in the cases of "tio, kio" and "tion, kion", but what about "tio, kion"? For example, "Tiu ago estas tio, kion faris la afero" (I think one would normally say something much simpler, like "La afero faris tiun agon", so this is just a contrived example). Because "tion" never follows "esti" (intransitivity?), I'm not sure if this convention would also apply here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it can be omitted there too:

```
Estas makaronioj [tio], kion ni manĝas.
```

Pli da informo: [PMEG - Rilata kio](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/subfrazoj/rilataj/kiu_kio_kies/kio.html)

Comment: While _tio_ can be omitted there too, the whole sentence is a special construction called _emfaza frazturno_ of which PMEG says: "Tiajn frazturnojn oni ne trouzu. Ofte oni povas emfazi pli facile per la vortordo."